Kanban, but with more information visible in the overview
I'm looking for ways to improve the organization of my work. I typically have about 10 projects open. I'm looking for a way to get an overview of the status of each project in one window.
This seems very similar to a Kanban board. I've tried Trello, and its main drawback is that only the task titles are visible in the overview.

In this example, the title is visible, and I can see how many check boxes are open.
If I want to see the status of the project, I have to open the task card.
What I want is to have one window that displays not just the task titles, but a one-paragraph summary of each task:
Example project
Status: made initial version of the script, waiting for feedback
[1/3]

Could you show what kind of information is missing on Trello and where? I'm not sure I follow

I've updated the question to clarify.
